# How can I efficiently insert data in three tables based on foreign keys?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, relational-database

So I have this database with three tables: `posts`, `authors` and `categories` where authors is the foreign key in posts table and posts is the foreign key in categories table. Now I can insert data in all of them in 3 different queries but I'm not sure if that is the right way performance wise.

The json data looks like this:

```
[
   {
       "post":"post1",
       "author":"Dan Brown",
       "category":[
            {
                 "catName":"Thriller"
            }
       ],
       "id":1
   }
]
```

This is how the tables look like :

```
const createInitialTables = `
                    CREATE TABLE authors (
                        id serial not null primary key,
                        author_name text not null unique check (author_name <> ''),
                        author_slug text not null unique check (author_slug <> '')
                    );

                    CREATE TABLE posts (
                        id serial not null primary key,
                        post text not null check (post <> ''),
                        post_slug text not null check (post_slug <> ''),
                        author_id serial not null,
                        CONSTRAINT fk_authors FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES authors(id)
                    );

                    CREATE TABLE categories (
                        id serial not null primary key,
                        category_name text not null check (category_name <> ''),
                        category_slug text not null check (category_slug <> ''),
                        post_id serial not null,
                        CONSTRAINT fk_posts FOREIGN KEY(post_id) REFERENCES posts(id)
                    );

                `;
```

```
const insertAuthor = `
      INSERT INTO authors (id, author_name, author_slug) 
      VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Dan Brown', 'dan-brown');
`;

const insertPost = `
      INSERT INTO posts (id, post, post_slug, author_id) 
      VALUES (DEFAULT, 'post1', 'post1', (SELECT id FROM authors WHERE author_name='Dan Brown'));
`;

const insertCategory = `
      INSERT INTO categories (id, category_name, category_slug, post_id) 
      VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Thriller', 'thriller', (SELECT id FROM posts WHERE post='post1'));
`;

await pool.query( insertAuthor );
await pool.query( insertPost );
await pool.query( insertCategory );
```

So my question is, is this the right way to do as my data array is around 50k in length. And I need to loop over the array and insert those into the database. Your suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The engine returns the newly create `ID` for the first insert using standard calls. You should use this id in the second insert, intead of selecting from the table; that's a brittle, bad strategy you should avoid.

Answer (score 0):

In principle this is okay, but i would recommand some changes:

1. Wrap your Queries in an [Transaction](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html). If one of your `Insert` Statements fail all your `Insert` Statements fail and your database don't end up in an inconsistent state.
2. Use [Prepared Statements](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-prepare.html). This gives the database engine the chance to parse the query and do some optimizations before you execute it.
3. Make sure to prevent [SQL-Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You are using interpolated strings for your queries which are vulnerable for such an attack. An attacker could insert malicious data in your json data set.

Also, you can insert multiple rows at once: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-insert-multiple-rows/

Comment: Can you please provide an example based on my situation?

Comment: These recommendations are good. However, the ID used in the second insert needs to be recoved from the first insert in a standard manner.